# Output list element in Python function "any"

Tags: python, list, any

I'm new at Python and I cannot manage to output day correctly within         `any` function. `Any`function returns `True` or `False`, but I would like to output element of list. Example below:

```
days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"]
if any(day in content.lower() for day in days):
    print day
```

I would like to print which day, function has found in string "content". Content has only one day at a time. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
print [day for day in days if day in content.lower()]
```

This will give you a list of all matching days.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because is more generic. I have an example where I have only one day in a string, but in case of multiple days, this one is the way to go. Thanks guys! Problem solved :)

Comment: @marc_s note that this also allows you to *check* that you only have one day in the string (e.g. `if len(matching_days) == 1:`); it's always good to know when your data isn't quite what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the first day it matches, you can also do -

```
>>> content = "tuesday"
>>> print(next(day for day in days if day in content.lower()))
tuesday
```

Comment: This answer works for me, since I have only one day in string. For other cases the answer below is better solution. Thank you.